# Defining an enum in C

Tags: c, linux, enums

I am a little bit surprised the following code does not compile. Can you shed some light on it? (header file)

```
enum CarType_e {
    CAR_BMW = 0,
    CAR_KIA,
    CAR_HONDA,
    CAR_FORD,
    CAR_MERCEDES
};

int build_car(CarType_e type);
```

and then I get the following error:

```
In file included from car.c:19:0:
car.h:35:16: error: unknown type name ‘CarType_e’
```

This is gcc version 4.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices, use

```
typedef enum {
  CAR_BMW = 0,
  CAR_KIA,
  CAR_HONDA,
  CAR_FORD,
  CAR_MERCEDES
} CarType_e;
```

Or, you can use -

```
int build_car(enum CarType_e type);
```

I tested both with gcc on linux.

Comment: The funny thing is that I have some code like that from an old development and I never had problems compiling. Could be a different behaviour between C versions? Or different compiler options?

Comment: @fazineroso Well yes it could be the compiler options (and/or command - g++ vs gcc).

Answer (score 3):

You need to say `enum CarType_e` wherever you use it:

```
int build_car(enum CarType_e type);
```

Or `typedef` the enum.

```
typedef enum {
    CAR_BMW = 0,
    CAR_KIA,
    CAR_HONDA,
    CAR_FORD,
    CAR_MERCEDES
} CarType_e;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, custom types (enums, unions, and structs) each have their own naming scope.

You need to write `int build_car(enum CarType_e type);`.
This also means there is no point in the `_e` suffix.

Alternatively, you can use `typedef`.

Comment: The funny thing is that I have some code like that from an old development and I never had problems compiling. Could be a different behaviour between C versions? Or different compiler options?

Comment: No; it's different behavior in different languages (C and C++). Don't compile C with a C++ Compiler just like you don't compile C with a FORTRAN compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler that you are using an enum by specifying its *tag along with the `enum` keyword*. Otherwise how would the compiler resolve an ambiguity like

```
struct foo { int x; char y; };
enum   foo { CAR, BIKE, ROCKET };
union  foo { int x; char y; };

int build_car (foo x);   /* A struct foo or an enum foo or a union foo? */
```

Note that structs, enums and unions all have a separate tag name space, so I am free to reuse the same tag name for each of them as shown above.

Requiring the tag name as in

```
int build_car (enum foo x);
int build_bike (struct foo x);
int build_rocket (union foo x);
```

makes this non-ambiguous for the compiler.

**And don't bother with typedefs for structs/unions; they are useless** and only the unenlightened would consider them. Yes, that's a strong opinion. All they do is save you from writing `struct` in a few places--that's some information you rather want to know about.

Comment: And how can I tell the compiler to use an enum by just specifying the tag?

Comment: You can't; a tag name by itself is not a type in C (C++ surely differs). You can however create a type with `typedef enum { CAR, BIKE, ROCKET } vehicle;` and then use `vehicle v` similar to `int v` everywhere you like. Syntactically, `vehicle` is a typedef-name, not a tag.